# Linux Mint (Ubuntu based), apache2 Configuration error: No MPM loaded

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

How to resolve apache2 configurationerror on Linux Mint (Ubuntu based): `AH00534: apache2 Configuration error: No MPM loaded`

I am following the first example of "Apache 3rd ed.. Laurie, Ben. ;Laurie, Peter. ;2007 ". It is named site.toddle

The file "/usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf" :

```
User webuser
Group webgroup

ServerName my586

DocumentRoot /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/htdocs
```

I try to run the command:

```
/usr/www/apache3/site.toddle $  apache2ctl -f `pwd`/conf/httpd.conf -d `pwd`
```

I am getting the error:

```
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
Action '-f /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf/httpd.conf -d /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle' failed.
```

I tried to work with different modules, like mpm_prefork, mpm_event (only one module enabled per single trial, apache restarted each time i change th emodule). I also reinstalled all apache. But this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The error have disappeared than i added lines:

```
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf
```

to file /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf/httpd.conf, which is supposed to overwrite the original file in Linux Mint directory:

```
 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```